# Photos faces lost after full restore through Time Machine

Tags: macos, time-machine, photos, catalina, restore

I recently did a full restore through Time Machine with my MacBook Pro (Early 2015). I have just opened the Photos app and realised that all face recognition data appears to be lost. So I have a few questions regarding this:

Is it possible to get this organization back?

Comment: Is photoanalysisd running in activity monitor ? And does the faces album say that it is processing stuff ?